# How can I install a package without root access?

Tags: software-installation

I have **no root access** on this machine.

I would like to know if there is a way I **can download Ubuntu packages and install them as non-root?**

Probably in my `~/bin` or `~/usr/share` or something like that? Would that work?

Comment: Hopefully, they will support it soon.

Comment: You could use portable apps for linux: no installing , no root necessary. Find it at http://appimage.org/. Even Linus Torvalds likes it. That's odd, cause Linus never likes anything.

Comment: I suggest trying [fakechroot](https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot).

Comment: A combination of `dpk -x` and `mv` worked for me. Or, if even `dpk` is not available, `ar` and piping/combining with `tar` worked for me on very restricted systems, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1059005)

Comment: Related on [unix.se]: [Non-Root Package Managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/non-root-package-managers)

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges/727461#727461

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Apt doesn't support it directly, but there are ways to do it:

### `.deb` Approach

```bash
apt-get download package_name  # replace `package_name` with the name of the package.

dpkg -x package.deb dir
```

If the `deb` isn't in the Ubuntu repositories, `apt-get download package_name` won't work, but you may be able to download it from a web site.

This will extract the `.deb` package to `dir/`. Then you can export the `PATH` where the binary is. As long as all dependencies of the binary are installed, it should run as normal.

### `schroot` Approach

Another approach is to use `schroot` to create a non-root chroot. This is a somewhat [involved process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot), but one you should be able find community help for as many developers set up chroot environments for compiling code.

### `apt-get source` Approach

Finally, you could use the `apt-get source` command to fetch the source of the package and configure it to install locally. Usually this looks something like:

```
apt-get source package
cd package
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

The disadvantage to this approach is that you need the development environment available for this approach to work at all, and you might find yourself compiling dozens of packages in order to resolve all the dependencies.

### Historical Approach

It used to be possible to install `package.deb` with `dpkg` into one's home directory.

```
dpkg -i package.deb --force-not-root --root=$HOME
```

The disadvantage to using `dpkg` like this is that error messages are likely to be cryptic; dpkg doesn't automatically resolve dependencies or create the directory structure it expects.

Comment: If you have root access but just don't want to install a particular package globally, you could use `sudo apt-get build-dep package` to install everything required to *build* a package (after getting its source with `apt-get source`).

Comment: the instructions to create a chroot seem to require root privileges ...
Is there a way to use chroot without needing such privileges ?

Comment: @josinalvo, check for schroot

Comment: You could also build a deb package that installs somewhere beside the usual system directories, but that would be extremely eccentric. Though occasionally done, usually by corporate entities like Google.

Comment: This answer was written back in 2010. Have there been any changes to how this is done since then?

Comment: I just tried using method 2 (dpkg -i) and I'm getting the following error. Any ideas?
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory

Comment: Even with --force-not-root, I get "dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege"

Comment: Folks, `--force-not-root --root=$HOME`, or variations thereof will not work. Debian binary packages are not designed to be installed in the home directory, period. Or, to put this another way,. "The following example will install package.deb into your home directory.". No, it won't.

Comment: Sadly this won't work. I tried `--force-not-root --root=/your/custom/path`

Comment: @krasnaya, there are a few files/directories you'll need to create within your intended install dir: `touch status`, `mkdir updates`, and there may be one or two more. Use the error messages that appear to guide you.

Comment: `dpkg -x <package.deb> <dir>` this worked for me.  
things i learned that once you ran this command don't export <dir> but instead export path where binary files of that package are present e.g. I exported this path `/path/to/dir/usr/bin/` with this command `export PATH="/path/to/dir/usr/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Note that some binary packages such as bison have binaries that include hard-coded paths to files such as /usr/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4. For such packages, a non-root working installation is impossible using dpkg -x and the only way to install non-root is by building from source.

Comment: how does it know where the package is after I download i.e. how does `dpkg -x package.deb dir` work?

Comment: @CharlieParker, `dpkg -x package.deb <dir>` just extracts the package, and the system doesn't know where it is.  That's why you have to `export PATH=$PATH:<dir>`.

Answer (score 19):

I assume you want to install [jedit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/editors/jedit). First you have to find the package and download it. I just take the [deb file from some mirror](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jedit/jedit_4.3.1.dfsg-0ubuntu1_all.deb) and open a console/terminal:

1. `mkdir /tmp/jedit && cd /tmp/jedit` -- Makes a new diretory in `tmp` and changes into it.
2. `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jedit/jedit_4.3.1.dfsg-0ubuntu1_all.deb` -- Download package
3. `ar x jedit_4.3.1.dfsg-0ubuntu1_all.deb` or, easy to type, `ar x *.deb` -- this extracts the file contents
4. `tar xvzf data.tar.gz` -- the file `data.tar.gz` has all the stuff which you need for executing the software
5. `usr/bin/jedit` opens the editor
6. done :-)

You can move the files to some point in your home directory and execute them from there.

Comment: Note that pre- and post-install scripts don't get run; also you'll need to resolve any dependencies or paths yourself.

But on a default install this is sufficient for a lot of desktop applications.

Comment: you can also download the package without searching for it, just do apt-get download (see other answer)

Comment: i believe your link is broke.

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a program called [JuNest](https://github.com/fsquillace/junest) which basically allows to have a really tiny Linux distribution (containing just the package manager) inside your $HOME/.junest directory.

It allows you to have your custom system inside the home directory accessible via proot and, therefore, you can install any packages without root privileges. It will run properly under all the major Linux distributions, the only limitation is that JuNest can run on Linux kernel with minimum recommended version 2.6.32.

For instance, after installing JuNest, to install jedit:

```
$>junest -f
(junest)$> pacman -S jedit
(junest)> jedit
```

Comment: This will run just fine on Ubuntu right?

Comment: Yes, if the linux kernel version of ubuntu is greater or equal to 2.6.32 it will work.

Comment: At first I thought you were talking about [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/juju). The second capitalized j makes the difference.

Comment: The question was if we could install Ubuntu package. With junest, we will only be able install  ArchLinux package and NOT an Ubuntu package. For e.g. if the same package is not available for ArchLinux, then this won't help. That said, thanks for Junest.

Comment: juju is junest now, and it works because of proot

Answer (score 1):

I find the accepted answer lacks a concrete example. This is a full working example:

```
# - opam (snap, no sudo)
# ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access
apt-get download opam
#apt-get download opam_1.2.2-4_amd64
#ls | less
mkdir -p ~/.local
dpkg -x opam_1.2.2-4_amd64.deb ~/.local/bin
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.user

tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"

opam --version
```

in particular you need to be careful because apt-get download might now give you the .deb fine with the exact name you expect.

Note this one usually also works:

```
# - install the bin then put it in path and restart your bash
mkdir ~/.rbenv
cd ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git .

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
#    exec $SHELL
#bash

rbenv -v
```

Comment: btw, don't install opam that way. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708063/how-does-one-install-opam-without-sudo-priveledges-on-linux-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1