# Install as user (not root) with aptitude to bin and lib in $HOME

Tags: installation, users, aptitude

I need to install some programs on a server where I cannot get super user privileges. Is there a flag or some way to get aptitude to install in my bin and lib folders in my home directory instead of for the whole system?

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/28619/3940) may give you further ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these commands must be run as root or with superuser privileges

Comment: That's depressing for me, but thanks for quick answer :)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to [how to create debian package to install files to /home/user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23464/11908) on the [Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

> The whole point of a Debian package is to install system-wide software. Think about it: if multiple users install this package to their respective /home/user/myapp area, what should show up in your package manager?
>
> If you want to install to your home directory, use the original source (eg. tarball) distribution.

Comment: Well, it would show up different things for different users in the package manager. The package manager `cabal-install` for Haskell allows user installs and system-wide installs and it works well :)