# Create new admin account with other account's software already installed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, aptitude

I have an admin account(say X) where I have installed some 50 software packages. Now I want to create another admin account(say Y) who can use all 50 software packages.

Is this possible? How do I share the software packages installed on one user account with another?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What kind of software packages are you talking about. Software packages are installed on the system and all users shall have access to them. So I do not see why you need to install them for another user. They should be there for all users, unless you are talking about some special software packages that I have never heard of.

Comment: @nobody software like Skype, Android Studio for instance, it doesn't appear on other account.

Comment: I believe Skype should work unless you copied binaries to home of the first user. However, you should enter user's credential for each user. For Android Studio i think the problem is, that this one actually installs to home directory of a user. For this one copy the app installation to the new user and it will probably work. Maybe you need to setup some paths. I am not sure. It really depends on each application, how it works and how it is setup. Generally applications should not be installed in the home directory if you ask me.

Comment: @nobody Yes, most packages are already shared across all users, but a few aren't. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Ubuntu package management installs all applications for all users.

This will not stop you from [manually installing additional applications to a user's HOME directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28619/how-do-i-install-an-application-by-deb-file-for-a-single-user-only). In this case you will have to copy this installation over to the other user's HOME.

Most applications will store user defined settings in a user's HOME. Most but depending on the application not all setting may also just be copied over to a new account to make them identical.

A special case are virtual machine's hard drives or Wine bottles that will be stored in a user's HOME by default. To use these from all accounts we can either make a copy resp. clone them to the other account, or we make sure we store these in a [shared directory accessible to multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users).