# How can I edit the config files of BlueJ without root permissions?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

In school I use ubuntu in my programmers class and we use BlueJ. This IDE is set to german language but I want to have an english IDE because I´m also programming in english. But to achieve this I have to modify a specific textfile. This file only can be accessed when you have root permissions. Is there any "inofficial" way to change this file without root permissions?

Comment: Just ask the sysadmin to change it.

Comment: If he would agree I wouldn´t ask here -.-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used BlueJ but most applications have their default, system-wide config files, which should not be modified by users (and if that's what your sysadmin refuses to modify, he might be right in doing so) but also a user-specific config files in $HOME/. Looking at its [documentation](http://www.bluej.org/doc/bluej-ref-manual.pdf) p.30, BlueJ can be invoked like this:

```
java -jar bluej.jar -Dbluej.language=german
```

and it also has a user-specific configuration file in:

```
<USER_HOME>/.bluej/bluej.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing a version of BlueJ onto your home directory (see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) or try the jar) and using this instead of the one supplied by your college. Or use an alternative IDE like eclipse - again installed on your home dir.

However, to actually answer the question if the file you need to edit

```
<bluej_dir>/lib/bluej.defs
```

Has specific permissions that your user account does not have access to then there isn't much you can do. Can you `ls -l` the file? This will tell you what permissions the file has and who is allowed to edit it. I'd be surprised if the preferences file was only editable by the `root` user.