# Find and download a package without sudo using aptitude

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo, aptitude

I would like to install a bunch of packages (glogg, libprotobuf7, libleveldb1, libsnappy1, libhdf5-7) on an Ubuntu system on which I do not have root privileges. (I understand that this can be achieved by forcing the downloading and installation to take place on my home directory for example).

I would like to do this as fast as possible, e.g using `apt` (rather than manually searching the web for a link address to the package, then `wget`-ing it, then opening the tarball, then reading the INSTALL file to install correctly etc).

Is there a way to do this?

[How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) has a 1st answer that assumes that we have the `.deb` file already downloaded. This is not my case (and if you know of a way to get it quickly without scouring the web, I'd love to know).

Comment: For the record, `aptitude` and `apt-get` are two different frontends.

Comment: The `deb` packages that are downloaded for installation don't contain `INSTALL` files, and are meant to be read by `dpkg` to be parsed and installed. Also, note that the packages contain two files: `data.tar.xz`, which contain the files to be installed relative to `/`, and `control.tar.xz`, which contain metadata about the package (package name, dependencies, installed size, etc.) and any configuration scripts.

Comment: what are you trying to install

Comment: You can download the package by using `apt-get download <package_name>` without root access and follow the answer in that question

Comment: I've modified the proposed duplicate to make it one by adding how to get the .deb from the repositories.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in one of the comments, use `apt-get` just to download, then `dpkg -i` to install.

```
mkdir $HOME/.local
apt-get download <package_name>
dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME/.local <package_name.deb>
```

Note: what's nice is that `apt-get` automatically picks the package that fits your Ubuntu distribution and your architecture.

Comment: `aptitude download <package_name>` will also work.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the following would work to install the package to a directory: ~/local/

Download the package as package.deb using :

```
apt-get download <package_name>
```

Then run

```
dpkg --install package.deb --instdir=~/local
```

Comment: Results in `dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege`, does not fix the requested issue.