# Chrome standalone for linux (no root)

Tags: google-chrome, root

Since i don't have root user password, is there anyway to install google chrome with it's dependencies ? (64 Bit)

Comment: see here.http://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access

Comment: actually chrome got lots of dependencies that i have to install too. And also they got many dependencies etc. It's kinda so hard.. Is there any other ways ?

Comment: If you are installing something locally, you need to provide all the dependency locally because it can't access the other library file from the system

Comment: ok so it's impossible...

Comment: not impossible but little tedious.

Comment: i wasted my 5 hours to install all dependencies and i couldn't make it work..prolly still needs some more dependencies..

Answer (score -1):

Just use chromium, you extract it from zip and, in my case, ./chrome --no-sandbox

Comment: Can you please provide a link to download Chromium, as well as instructions to unzip it? Use the [edit] button to add this information to your post.

Comment: Also, Chromium is not exactly Chrome. You should probably make that clear.