# How do I do this "install: you may need to run ldconfig"

Tags: readline

I need to install `readline` on a Linux server. Since I don't have `sudo` access, I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) instruction but I got into a problem.

I've installed `readline` by using `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. In the end it asks me `install: you may need to run ldconfig`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I've installed readline by using `./configure, make, make install`. At
>   the end it ask me `install: you may need to run ldconfig`.

So you just need to run the command

```
sudo ldconfig
```

#### What is ldconfig

ldconfig is a program that is used to maintain the shared library cache. This cache is typically stored in the file `/etc/ld.so.cache` and is used by the system to map a shared library name to the location of the corresponding shared library file

`man ldconfig`

```
 ldconfig - configure dynamic linker run-time bindings

DESCRIPTION
       ldconfig  creates,  updates,  and removes the necessary links and cache
       (for use by the run-time linker,  ld.so)  to  the  most  recent  shared
       libraries  found  in  the directories specified on the command line, in
       the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib  and
       /lib).   ldconfig  checks the header and file names of the libraries it
       encounters when determining which  versions  should  have  their  links
       updated.  ldconfig ignores symbolic links when scanning for libraries.
```

For more information see : [What-does-ldconfig-do?](http://www.quora.com/What-does-ldconfig-do)

---

UPDATE: solution for `-bash: ldconfig: command not found`

As told in comments below when you ran the `echo $PATH` gives

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

while `ldconfig` is inside /sbin which is outside the PATH, so you have then either to run the commands by absolute path like `/sbin/ldconfig` or correct your path.

To correct your PATH do  the following:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Now save and exit then source `.bashrc`

```
source .bashrc
```

So now you can use the commands directly

Comment: I'm running these commands on a server and I don't have root access. It's not possible to run sudo ldconfig 
and when I executed ldconfig command , it said 
-bash: ldconfig: command not found

Comment: output of `ldconfig --version`?

Comment: -bash: ldconfig: command not found

Comment: what is the output of the command `echo $PATH`

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Comment: Run the command `PATH=$PATH:/sbin` then run the command `ldonfig` again

Comment: read the update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24376/discussion-between-mehrshad-and-maythux).

Comment: `sbin` programs are typically administrative programs intended to be executed only by the root user, and `ldconfig` is no exception. If `ldconfig` is not on the `PATH`, that probably means that a non-root user is trying to execute it, *not* that the `PATH` is improperly set up. So the *typical* solution is almost certainly `sudo ldconfig` or `su; ldconfig`, not path-editing.

Comment: Mershad's case may be an exception, since they don't have root access (but they're still making changes to the system....), but it would be well worth mentioning in your answer that this is not *typical*, and that there's a good reason why `ldconfig` might not be on the path.