# How can i update a software without password in 18.04?

Tags: updates, vim

My problem is in my University's library, all the PC have Ubuntu, while thats not a problem, all the software are not updated, which is very much a problem.
For me, Vim is a very much needed tool for programming,but all the system in my University's library have a older version, where "A,B,C,D etc etc" are taken as a input when i click arrows key.

Comment: I would ensure you are running `vim` and not `vi`.  The original `vi` didn't know what arrow keys were (*there were no standards for arrow keys (or really each make as it's own standard), plus most dumb terminals back then didn't have arrow keys anyway, esp. those found at universities*).

Comment: @karel That's wrong, though. It's absolutely possible to install software on a system that one doesn't fully control. Users can install software inside their own home directories (and in my experience administrators often *prefer* that to installing it systemwide themselves, though they should be consulted rather than have their intentions assumed if there's concern). One can build from source with `./configure --prefix="$HOME"` or [use a package manager that supports that use case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535). (I'll try and see if we already have an answered question about this.)

Comment: Related, though not ideal for this use case: [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Answer (score -1):

You either need to know root password or you need to be authorized to use `sudo` command if you want to update/install software.

When you are authorized to use `sudo` there are two possibilities - either you can use it without a password or you have to provide *your* password, it depends on how admin set up your account.