# How can I install software on an user computer (no root access)?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I tried to install software on a user computer at my university, but I couldn't.  Every time I try to install it, it says that I don't have authorisation.

So is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. To install software on any system (not only linux), you would normally require root (administrator) privileges. Please clarify (by editing your question) how you are trying to install software. Also note that, Ubuntu 19.10 (if that is indeed what you are using) is not released yet and therefore the question would be off-topic on this site for another week...

Comment: Although I think the question is not specific to 19.10 but seems like a duplicate of [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Comment: It's not really my area, guys. But thank you so much for the clarifications.

Comment: Also related: [How can i update a software without password in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175163/how-can-i-update-a-software-without-password-in-18-04) The best ways can depend on what you're trying to install. For example, some software is readily available through [general-purpose non-root package managers like Nix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8665/11938). Some is available through package managers like `npm`, `pip`, or `cpan`, that are often already available. Some is easy to build from source code. I recommend you **[edit]** with details of *what* you wan to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have user access (and not root access) to an Ubuntu system you would basically have two options to install software:

- compile the programs yourself with all paths set to userspace (ie. within your home directory)
- use portable versions of the programs you use (programs that function from within their own directory)

Portable applications are available in repositories such as 
[AppImageHub](https://appimage.github.io/apps/) (for [AppImage apps](https://appimage.org/)) or if the system has Wine installed sites like [PortableApps](https://portableapps.com/apps).

Comment: Does portableapps.com offer packages for Linux? I'm not sure it does.

Comment: @DKBose you're right... I just saw the linux logo but they're not native and require wine... appimage files are the right answer of course... just didn't remember the name earlier

Comment: Yes, I like AppImages as well if they're available!