# Install Ubuntu packages without sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo

I am trying to install the code here https://github.com/FORTH-ModelBasedTracker/MonocularRGB_3D_Handpose_WACV18 but do not have sudo permissions on the server that I am using in my school. I have been given an account on that server but do not have sudo permissions. The installation requires me to run the following command

```
sudo apt install libgoogle-glog-dev libtbb-dev libcholmod3.0.6 libatlas-base-dev libopenni0 libbulletdynamics2.83.6
```

How can I run that command or install the code without sudo ?

EDIT: Thanks all. I thought there would be a way to locally install these things like how we can install things (like numpy) in a conda environment. I can run conda btw.

Comment: There is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges), but you should just check with the admin/IT department. If you don't have sudo access, they may well not want you installing stuff. It's probably a good idea to get permission before violating what might be their intent.

Comment: If you don't have sudp rights on the server, it is because you are not supposed to do sys.adm. stuff like installing software. Ask your teacher what the procedure is to get software you need for your study, installed on the server.

Comment: We really shouldn't help you violate your school's security policy. Talk to the system administrator if you need sudo.

Comment: No sudo = No install. Installing unauthorized software on a computer that isn't yours is a criminal act in many jurisdictions. Even if your school doesn't call the police, you risk suspension, expulsion or a hefty bill for a professional cleanup of the mess you cause. And forget about any letters of recommendation. DON'T do it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there would be a way to locally install these things that is specific only for me like installing stuffs (numpy etc) in a conda environment. I can run conda btw.

Comment: python3-pip can install Python packages locally in Ubuntu, but there remains the problem of requiring sudo to install python3-pip. python3-virtualenv can create a Python virtual environment that doesn't require sudo to install Python packages in the Python virtual environment .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)